# Why isn't this property being serialized in my mvc project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

The ultimate goal is to serialize an `abstract` type from my `View` to be consumed by my `Controller`.

My abstract type has an `enum` property whose names correspond to the names of the concrete derived types; this is how I will determine which concrete type to select.  The value of this `enum` is set in the constructor of the abstract type via reflection:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(BlockJsonConverter)]
public abstract class Block{

   [NotMapped, JsonProperty]
   public BlockType BlockType {get; set;}
   public string Name {get;set:}
   public int Height{get;set;}
   public int Width {get;set;}
   public int Depth {get;set;}

   protected Block(){
      BlockType = Enum.TryParse(GetType().Name, out BlockType blocktype)
             ?? blocktype : BlockType.Unknown
   }
}

public enum BlockType {
   Long, Short, Tall, Unknown
}

public class Long    : Block { /*...*/ }
public class Short   : Block { /*...*/ }
public class Tall    : Block { /*...*/ }
public class Unknown : Block { /*...*/ }
```

The `Block` class is used by Entity Framework but the `BlockType` property is not stored in the database, so the `BlockType` property is marked with the `[NotMapped]` attribute; however, since I want the property to be round-tripped from the View to the Controller, I have marked it with the `[JsonProperty]` attribute.

I have created a `TestModelBinder` to handle the deserialization from the View to the Controller:

```
public class TestModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
       ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext,
            GetModelType(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType));
    }

    protected override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(
      ControllerContext controllerContext,ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelType = GetModelType(controllerContext, bindingContext, bindingContext.ModelType);
        return new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(modelType)
                      .GetTypeDescriptor(modelType);
    }

    private static Type GetModelType(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
        Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType.Name == "Block")
        {
• breakpoint
           // get the value from bindingContext for BlockType
           // and return the concrete type based on that
        }
        return modelType;
    }
}
```

**When I hit that breakpoint above, the `bindingContext` does not have a `BlockType` in its `ValueProvider.FormValueProvider` for my `BlockType` property - but the `Name`, `Height`, `Width` and `Depth` properties are listed as expected.**

They're all listed the same way in the EditorTemplate:

```
@model Block
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        @Html.BootstrapEditorGroupFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>        
    <div class="col">
        @Html.BootstrapEditorGroupFor(m => m.BlockType)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        @Html.BootstrapEditorGroupFor(m => m.Height)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        @Html.BootstrapEditorGroupFor(m => m.Width)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        @Html.BootstrapEditorGroupFor(m => m.Depth)
    </div>
</div>
```

... and the `BootstrapEditorGroupFor` helper just generates the usual label, editor based on type (enum, string, etc), and validation message.  The EditorTemplate for Enums is below:

```
@model Enum

@{
    var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType) 
               ?? ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType;
}

<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control">
        @if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType)
        {
            <option selected="@ReferenceEquals(Model, null)">Not Specified</option>
        }
        @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(type))
        {
            <option selected="@value.Equals(Model)">@value</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first block of code contains a null-coalescing operator followed by a value, and then a colon ([...]`?? blocktype : BlockType.Unknown`). Was that supposed to be a ternary operator?

Comment: Your select element doesn't seems to be rendering the name of the element. Without name the data will not get matched to the appropriate property in you model. You can double check it by just editing the HTML in your browser and adding an attribute `name="BlockType"` to your `select`

Comment: @IPValverde You have pointed me in the right direction.  Repost your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select element doesn't seems to be rendering the `name` of the element. Without the `name` attribute the data will not get matched to the appropriate property in you model.
You can double check it by just editing the HTML in your browser and adding an attribute `name="BlockType"` to your select input and try posting the form to see if it works.